# How can I tell when the Angular2 online documentation (or any website) changes?

Tags: documentation, angularjs

I'm trying to keep up-to-date with the latest-greatest from Angular2, in part by carefully reading the [official online documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/). Is there a way to be notified or at least to figure out relatively painlessly whether, when and where that documentation has changed?

With Angular2 being so new, the documentation is understandably under construction. You occasionally find sentences like the following: "A future chapter update will explain how to write such tests with the RouterTestingModule."

The documentation urls include "angular.io/docs/ts/latest/..." (note the generic "latest") and thus don't include any indication of documentation identity (e.g. a documentation version identifier, a date, etc.). There are also no textual indicators, e.g. "Section 4 (updated Oct 9, 2016)".

So let's say that tomorrow the Angular team finally uploads the RouterTestingModule mentioned in my above example. How would I know that? Do I have to manually scan the documentation at regular intervals?! That would be a LOT of work, and even if I could do it, I'd have to remember what the old documentation was, and note whether and where any change happens. That seems impossible to me.

I'm trying to imagine how to do this: Are there archived old versions of the documentation (e.g. under "angular.io/docs/ts/<date>/...")? Can I sign up for email notification of changes? Are there tools available for me to create my own archives (of any website) that automatically scan a website for changes relative to my archive?

I can't imagine that this difficulty is specific to Angular2. It must happen everywhere. Are there "industry-standard" ways of figuring this out? Does Angular follow any such standard(s)?

I have heard of CDN, i.e. change detection and notification (here's a [brief Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_detection_and_notification)), but am not very familiar with it. Is this the route to go? Is this the simplest method?

*(If this is the wrong place to ask this question, please let me know where I could/should migrate it to?)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I've been reading the Angular2 documentation for several months, it appears that a new part of the Angular2 documentation (apparently introduced only 2 weeks ago, on Sept 24, 2016) is an actual [Documentation Change Log](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/change-log.html). I hadn't noticed this before as it is so new. External website tracker tools are still another theoretical possibility, but the change log is just so much simpler. Thank you Angular.

Comment: But you have to regularly read the change log? You can't be automatically motified when it is updated?

Comment: @Mawg, What you say is true. I don't know of a way to, say, get Google to notify me when they change the documentation or the documentation change log. However, manually checking one change log is at least way better than having to check all of the documentation itself. Beyond that, if I/you/we need to have automatic notification, then I guess we'll have to use some of the other change-detection-and-notification tools out there, such as the one you discuss in your answer...and thanks for that.

Comment: I feel your pain. While it's true that I regularly eyeball the Angular site, there are quite a few that I keep up with & the Change Detection site is a godsend. There has been, over the years, a marked fall-off in the ability to sign up to receive an email when a product is launched or updated :-(

Answer (score 2):

For more than a decade now, I have been using the excellent and free [Change Detection](http://changedetection.com/) service.

To quote:

> ChangeDetection.com provides page change monitoring and notification
>   services to internet users worldwide. Anyone can use our service to
>   monitor any website page for changes. Just fill in the form below, we
>   will create a change log for the page and alert you by email when we
>   detect a change in the page text. We've been doing it since 1999. It's
>   free.

Comment: I will definitely investigate this further.